# T-SQL: Trying to combine two queries into one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want a list of Customers and All their purchases from among Items A, B, C, D, E

BUT ...

Only for Customers who have purchased C or E.

Right now I'm thinking of something like this PSEUDO-CODE:

```
Select Customer, Item From Purchases
Where Items In (A, B, C, D, E)
And Customer In 
(
Select Customer From Purchases
Where Items In (C, E)
)
```

My actual query is much more complex, takes long to run and includes Customer information from multiple tables and purchases spread over multiple tables ... I am wondering if it is inefficient to run the Select statement twice - and whether I can do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

the answer depends on complexity, format and amount of your data
sometimes you can just replace `IN` by `EXISTS`
the other way is using `temp` tables - populate list of customers that use items C,E into temp tables and then use the temp table in your query

```
Select Customer, Item From Purchases p1
Where p1.Items In (A, B, C, D, E)
  and exists (
    select top 1 1 from Purchases p2 
      where p1.Customer = p2.Customer
        and p2.Items in (C,E))
```